# kaspersky blocking SOAP connections

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx

I have several web services in different integration environments. I used to be able to access them from local clients (winforms/wpf apps) but for the last few days I keep getting the below error.

> Could not connect to https://somehttpsservice/service.svc. TCP error
>   code 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden
>   by its access permissions someip:443.

Our computers come with kaspersky installed and managed by network admins remotely. We can't change or view the settings in their entirety. I don't know what to ask from the admins and what they could change to help out.

I recently narrowed down the symptoms to those below. I would like to be able to connect again or at least understand the problem.

- Client apps only work from certain folders.
- Copy-pasting the exact
  folder to anywhere else gets the above error on service calls.
- Changing user permissions to match exactly with working folders
  changes nothing.
- Client apps work fine in a vm.
- Build output folders also fail with the same error when not in respective folders they always work in.
- Turning off kaspersky completely is not an option.
- SOAP UI calls work fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you find answer to your problem with kaspersky?

Comment: @user3373603 Sort of. I turned on event logs to see errors like this: ...The Windows Filtering Platform has blocked a connection....  Turns out a windows service called Base Filtering Engine blocks the connection and turning it off fixed the issues. Not  I don't know anything further than this.